# How many shock absorbers are in washing machine LG F1480QDS?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I would like to disassemble my washing machine in order to replace all dampers. I would like to do it only after they get delivered because the appliance is not easily accessible so I want to save some effort doing the manipulation and disassembly twice. But I cannot figure out how many dampers actually are inside – how many I have to order. Two or three? (Or more?) I am unable to find reliable source.

Suitable shock absorbers have part number 383EER3001G.

Answers based on similar LG models can fit, too, I assume that they have similar design in the inside.

Comment: Is this not from USA? From what I have found online, this is a UK model and looks like from picture, that it uses 2. But The picture doesn't show exactly, just lists it twice.

Comment: Watching a video, it shows the replacement of 3. 2 forward and 1 rear.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6OmqREC0us&t=68s

Comment: @JeffCates – Thank you. Yes I have seen that video yet before asking and the model of the machine there seems way too old (15 years?). So I was afraid it may have substantial differences in design. Regarding the location info, it is in my profile. :) Anyway, I decided to disassemble the machine later today and post the info here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3.

I opened the washing machine and found three shock absorbers. Unlike on older LG models, these are now placed below the tub on sides: two on the left and one on the right.